# How to create a overlaySKScene SWIFT Xcode to display a HUD or controls?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a scene that is set up up with SceneKit. It's a game that uses SceneKit. I'm trying to make a HUD, so I can put controls on the screen by using SpriteKit. The problem is I don't quite have all the code and I don't know what I'm missing. Can you rewrite it correctly please? I tried to add a sprite image on the screen named base, but I'm not sure if that's how you add a child once you've cast the SpriteKit overlaySKScene?

Code:

```
  import iAd
  import UIKit
  import GameKit
  import SceneKit
  import StoreKit
  import SpriteKit
  import QuartzCore
  import Foundation
  import AVFoundation
  import AudioToolbox

  //============================================================
  class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKPhysicsContactDelegate, SKSceneDelegate, SCNSceneRendererDelegate, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate{

  let base = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"VirtualJoystickBase")


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    let skScene = scnView.overlaySKScene
    scnView.overlaySKScene = skScene
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    scnView.scene = FieldScene
    scnView.delegate = self
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnView.showsStatistics = false

     base.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    base.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-3.4, -5.2)
    scnView.overlaySKScene?.addChild(base)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is in these lines of code:

```
let skScene = scnView.overlaySKScene
scnView.overlaySKScene = skScene
```

This two lines are a place of completely useless actions. By default the `overlaySKScene` returns `nil` for its `scnView` because it has no SKScene. And you save this `nil` to `skScene` object, then set it back to `scnView.overlaySKScene` (even if there was not `nil`, it is absolutely useless to do this actions)

Then when you try to do this:

```
scnView.overlaySKScene?.addChild(base)
```

`addChild` did not call because of `scnView.overlaySKScene` is `nil`. That's why you have nothing at the end.

To fix this you need create `SKScene` object for example like this:

```
let overlayScene = SKScene(size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
```

Then you can set the `position` for your `base` object like this:

```
base.position = CGPointMake(50, 0)
```

Then add `base` object to scene:

```
overlayScene.addChild(base)
```

And finally set scene to overlay like this:

```
scnView.overlaySKScene = overlayScene
```